# jQuery Ajax: Failed to load resource with echo/json

Tags: jquery

Whenever I try to execute this code (got it from one of the SO threads) on my local machine I get an error

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

What am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "echo/json",
  type: "POST",
  data: {json: '{"message": "Hello"}', delay: 5},
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Also please tell the correct way.

Comment: does the location 'echo/json' exist relative to the script location? like if the JS AJAX call is in app/index.html does app/echo/json file exist?

Comment: Your url path is incorrect..

Comment: this looks like it was used in a jsFiddle, see: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#json

Comment: /echo/json exists in jsFiddle.  If you want to use it on your localhost, you have to configure that path to echo json.

Comment: @SuckerForMayhem yes probably. How can I make the above example work on a local machine. I want to run the above code and displau the "message" in a done() method after a delay of 5 seconds

Comment: @BarbaraLaird I am not really interested in echo/json. I just want to run the above code and display message in a done() method

Comment: @user1800987 create a text file like "data.json" and then create JSON data in that file (example [here](http://json.org/example.html)) then link to the file in the AJAX call using url: "folder_of_file/data.json" relative to the folder the script is in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a JSON file named data.json in the same folder as your HTML file:

```
{ message: "Hello" }
```

Call AJAX in a script inside an HTML file: (index.html):

```
<script>
// jQ DOM ready function:
$(function() {
  // AJAX call
  $.ajax({
    url: "data.json",
  }).done(function(data) {
    // When AJAX receives data from .json file

    // Set a 5 s timeout delay
    setTimeout(function() {
      // After 5s delay
      alert(data.message);
    }, 5000);
  });
});
</script>
```

Take a look at the jQuery AJAX method documention: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: if you want the delay after the done method receives the AJAX JSON data, you could use `setTimeout(function() { //code here }, 5000);` to delay the code from running for 5000milliseconds

Comment: nice but when I used the previous method, I could use a delay to delay the call by 5 seconds like this data: {json: '{"message": "Hello"}', delay: 5}. How do I do it now?

Comment: I would either use the `setTimeout` or look at the jQuery AJAX documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ to see if there are delay options, I haven't looked

Comment: I am confused too. The only option I could find was to specify in data as I had done earlier.

Comment: @user1800987 I think your best bet is using `setTimeout` I'll update my answer